# Beautiful Soup to scrape data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the EPS Estimates, EPS Earnings History (1st and 3rd tables) using BeautifulSoup from yahoo finance into an existing csv file. https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/analysis?p=MSFT

I have made a start but am struggling to be able to pull the exact data that I need, I am guessing I will need a for loop across the rows and td tags.

```
url = 'https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + index +'/analysis?p=' + index
response = get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

EP = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':"W(100%)"})
print(EP)
```

This appears be getting only the first table, but I am not sure how we write the loop to get the appropriate data. Looking at the HTML it looks like both the first and third tables have the same class name, so I can't use that to just go to the appropriate table.

Another idea I had, is searching for all tables on the page and putting them into a list. I could then select the correct index, but I'm not sure how I would do that in code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `soup.find` with `soup.find_all()`. It returns a list of all the tables, which you can then iterate.

```
EPs = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class':"W(100%)"})
for EP in EPs:
    ...
```

Your first and third tables would be `EPs[0]` and `EPs[2]` if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Bonus trick dataframe from html table: `import pandas as pd; df=pd.read_html(str(EP))`

Comment: @Feelx234 Hi thanks for the tip. I tried using this approach with the code you have written and then doing df.to_excel("Test.xlsx") but I get an error "list object has no attributes 'to_excel' I'm not sure why as I don't appear to be using a list anywhere?

Comment: read_html returns a list of dataframes.  Access the dataframes you want by indexing the list.  `dfs = pd.read_html(str(EP)), dfs[0], dfs[2]`

Comment: @Mathlearner, can you show the code of where you get df? Because as it says it is a list, and you have to loop through the list elements and convert each of them to excel